# Why do I have to run alsactl init each time I boot my system?

Tags: alsa

After a new update, there is no sound by default in my Debian Squeeze box until running `alsactl init`, but whenever rebooting the computer I have to run the command again to gain sound.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have tried `alsactl store'.

Comment: Are you sure that the `alsa` `init.d` script is starting?

Comment: Hi Let_Me_Be, there's only a file */etc/init.d/alsa-utils*.

Comment: Yes, that should be the `alsa` init script name in Debian based systems.

Comment: Does it help if you run `/etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart` once (after sound works)? Do you have a file `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`? When you have no sound, do applications that should produce sound emit error messages, or do you just hear nothing?

Comment: check your drivers...

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo alsactl store
```

to save mixer settings manually, it should work afterwards

Comment: Sounds like he [already tried it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15765/saving-alsa-settings/31630#comment21204_15765)